# How to build a docker image for cuda based c++ application runnig on Nvidia Jetson?

Tags: c++, docker, build, dockerfile, nvidia-jetson

To be more specific, my source code is compiled and linked successfully when I am running it from inside the container.
However, when I am trying to build the image from a Dockerfile it fails.
i.e.:

this works (These lines are from the terminal "inside" the container):

```
cd AppFolder; make; //success
```

this does not (These are lines from the dockerfile):

```
RUN git clone <url> && cd APPFolder && make
```

Now I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcuda.so.1 needed by...
```

How can I build the application from the dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between a container and a layer during the image build is the next layers. perhaps you are running the `RUN` directive to early - i.e. before the cuda library was generated?

try putting this command as low as you can in the Dockerfile

Comment: No, this is the last directive

Comment: another way to check if library exists is by adding `RUN find /usr/lib -name "libcuda*"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding "-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined" to the compiler/linker (g++) solved this issue. I think it "tells"  the linker to "remain" pointer to function that will be "linked" only in runtime (i.e., when **running** the docker image)